# GridView row editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview with five BoundFields.when inserting values to the grid i have got textbox fields to the cells and it's working fine.my issue is when editing a row i only need 3 cells to be editable and other two cells should left read only.how can i achieve this?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" CssClass="grid-view" 
        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PageSize="8"
            onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
            onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
            onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
            onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="5" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnInsert" runat="server" 
            Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" ForeColor="White" />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit-Update" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptID" HeaderText="Department ID" 
                ReadOnly="True" />
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptCode" HeaderText="Department Code"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptDescription" HeaderText="Description" />          

            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" />               
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code for inserting values to grid:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
    {
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT = PinCDAO.GetDepartments();
        DataRow DR = DT.NewRow();
        DT.Rows.InsertAt(DR, 0);

        GridView1.EditIndex = 0;
        GridView1.DataSource = DT;

        GridView1.DataBind();

        ((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text = "Insert";
    }
}
```

Row уditing code:

```
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
```

Inserting and updating:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    if (GetDeptCode())
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Already Contains a Department Code with the Same Name";
    }
    else if (CheckCodeLength())
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Department Code Character Length is 3";
    }
    else
    {
        if (((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text == "Insert")
        {
            DepertmentProperties DP = new DepertmentProperties();
            DP.DeptCode = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            DP.DeptDescription = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();

            PinCDAO.InsertDepartment(DP);
        }
        else
        {
            DepertmentProperties DP = new DepertmentProperties();
            DP.DeptID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString());
            DP.DeptCode = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();
            DP.DeptDescription = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text.ToString();

            PinCDAO.UpdateDepartment(DP);
        }
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
        lblMessage.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set [BoundField's ReadOnly property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.readonly.aspx) to "true"

Comment: i need the textboxes to be appear in all the cells when i'm inserting values to the grid.i only need the textboxes not to be appear in 3 cells when editing a row.so this doesn't work.

Comment: @chamara: GridView by default does not come with Insert functionality. So are you using some other control or some customization? And ReadOnly property affects the Edit only. Please clarify more and sharing some code will be more helpful.